# How to set java.home path in VS Code Remote Container

Tags: java, environment-variables, containers, visual-studio-code

How to set java.home path in VS Code Remote Container and I want to know how the path should be mentioned. I have the jdk in my local machine.

I tried pointing to local absolute path like **C:\jdk1.xxx** obviously it failed since local files can't be accessed inside a container.

I would like to know how the path should be specified for java home.